# Is there a tool in QGIS that has the same functionality as the ArcHydro Tools from ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis

I need a tool in QGIS that has the same functionality as the ArcHydro Tools from ArcGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS incorporates the functionality of the major open source GISes (GRASS, SAGA, ...) and thus you might hava a look at GRASS GIS `r.watershed` module, as far as I see its functionality is compareable to those of ArcHydro Tools. In this context consider also `r.water.outlet` and `r.gwflow`. Just type the name of the module in the search of the processing toolbox (Processing > Toolbox...):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[TauDEM](https://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/index.html) might be the toolset you are looking for.  TauDEM includes an ArcGIS toolbox if and only if you have ArcGIS installed on your Windows computer.